# Why this code stalls when calling ./prog ls ls wc 1.txt?

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork, dup2

when compiling this code and calling

```
./prog ls ls wc 1.txt
```

(supposed to be

```
(ls; ls) | wc > 1.txt
```

this code stalls and done right only after <kbd>Control-d</kbd>. What's the matter?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    if (!fork()) {
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        close(fd[1]);
        if (!(fork())) {
            execlp(argv[1], argv[1], NULL);
            _exit(1);
        }
        wait(NULL);
        if (!fork()) {
            execlp(argv[2], argv[2], NULL);
            _exit(1);
        }
        wait(NULL);
    }
    close(fd[1]);
    wait(NULL);
    if (!fork()) {
        dup2(fd[0], 0);
        close(fd[0]);
        int ffd = open(argv[4], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0600);
        dup2(ffd, 1);
        close(ffd);
        execlp(argv[3], argv[3], NULL);
        _exit(1);
    }
    close(fd[0]);
    wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm suspicious of not closing some file descriptors or pipe ends, but it seems to me I'm ok with them. So I dont understand why it doesnt work with ls ls wc(

Comment: You should set up the pipe (arg[3], arg[4]) *before* calling the two producers (ls,ls) , and connect the producers's output to them *before* calling them.

Comment: @wildplasser your comment finally made my code working. But I dont understand why (arg[3], arg[4]) cant just wait until ls ls produces output? Is it because ls ls cant write into pipe, which is not been reading by any one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exit the program in the first child process, otherwise both the original process and the child execute the code at the bottom that runs `wc` reading from the pipe.

Or you can put all that code in an `else` block, so it doesn't run in the child process.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    if (!fork()) {
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        close(fd[1]);
        if (!(fork())) {
            execlp(argv[1], argv[1], NULL);
            _exit(1);
        }
        wait(NULL);
        if (!fork()) {
            execlp(argv[2], argv[2], NULL);
            _exit(1);
        }
        wait(NULL);
    } else {
        close(fd[1]);
        wait(NULL);
        if (!fork()) {
            dup2(fd[0], 0);
            close(fd[0]);
            int ffd = open(argv[4], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0600);
            dup2(ffd, 1);
            close(ffd);
            execlp(argv[3], argv[3], NULL);
            _exit(1);
        }
        close(fd[0]);
        wait(NULL);
        return 0;
    }
}
```